# Python project versioning

Tags: python

### The problem:

I need to set versioning in my `python`project.
Every time I make a release - I merge my **production** and **development** branches in my VCS.
I need to make the least amount of corrections in setting up version of the project and automate the process.

### What I`ve done:

- I`ve read [PEP 396](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/) about module versioning (it is not exactly what I need)
- I figured out how to set up a version for the project with `setup.py` file in [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)
- I figured out how `django` works with its versions [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/__init__.py)

### My next steps:

I need for my release:

- release date
- revision
- version number

So I plan to make my release number format `major.minor.changeset`, because keeping the release date in the version makes it pretty long.
I want to create `version.py` file:

```
MAJOR_VERSION = 1
MINOR_VERSION = 1
RELEASE_DATE = '28 .08.2013 '


def get_revision ():
    ...

def get_version ():
   ....
```

And import the version from there when I need it (but I'm affraid that someone can forget to set up proper date), and put the file `CHANGE.TXT` next to it which describes release changes.

### The question:

I want to know how do you set versions in your `python` projects and how should I convert my idea to simplify my scheme.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing with what you have done so far?

Comment: Want to figure out what is the best practices to set versioning in python project.

Comment: Best practice type questions are not well-suited for StackOverflow because they are mostly based on opinions.

Comment: There are should be few practices that are often used, I think it will be helpful for somebody else too, not only me.

Comment: Great set up to a question that isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you can improve that tiny part of your question that is actually your question, then this would be a great fit.

Answer (score 5):

Two related issues: (1) what are good choices for metadata to track at the module level, including versioning, plus other useful information; and (2) what is a good way to represent that metadata.

A general approach for module metadata is explained at http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-fields.html#module-metadata-variables.  This basically says, use constants named `__author__`, `__authors__`, `__contact__`, `__copyright__`, `__license__`, `__date__` and `__version__`.  These are commonly used, so it's a good convention.

Then for how to populate the `__version__` constant -- a good model for versioning anything is semantic versioning -- see http://semver.org/.  Basically, use `1.2.3` style in which major changes only when there's an incompatible API change, minor changes when there's new functionality, and micro aka patch changes when there's a bug fix.  This is also used commonly and therefore a good convention.